# How to find the longest substring with no repeated characters?

Tags: string, algorithm, language-agnostic

I want an algorithm to find the longest substring of characters in a given string containing no repeating characters. I can think of an O(n*n) algorithm which considers all the substrings of a given string and calculates the number of non-repeating characters. For example, consider the string "**AABGAKG**" in which the longest substring of unique characters is 5 characters long which corresponds to **BGAKG**.

Can anyone suggest a better way to do it ?

Thanks

Edit: I think I'm not able to explain my question properly to others. You can have repeating characters in a substring (It's not that we need all distinct characters in a substring which geeksforgeeks solution does). The thing which I have to find is maximum no of non-repeating characters in any substring (it may be a case that some characters are repeated).

for eg, say string is **AABGAKGIMN** then **BGAKGIMN** is the solution.

Comment: Pretty off-topic question in its current form, but consider how you might use a `std::set` here.

Comment: u can use hash table and maintain 2 indexes and a counter, think of it.And u will get it in O(n)

Comment: Here is the link u should see , but I suggest please try to solve by yourself first ..............http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/length-of-the-longest-substring-without-repeating-characters/

Comment: If you are considering *all* the sub-strings, it's `O(n^3)` not `O(n^2)` but, as *Omkant* said, there is a `O(n)` solution to this problem.

Comment: Please look at the edit and let me know if things are still not clear.

Comment: @code_hacker If you can have repeating characters in the solution, why `BGAKGIMN` is a better solution than the string `AABGAKGIMN` itself ?

Comment: @zakinster: if we are considering all sub strings,it's O(n^3) how ? can you please explain. I thought we can do it in O(n^2)

Comment: @zakinster: no that won't be a good solution because the no. of non-repeating characters = 5 but my solution BGAKGIMN will give 6.

Comment: @code_hacker You would have `n*(n-1)/2` possible substrings with a mean length of `(n+1)/2`. Iterating over each character of each substrings would be `O(n^3)`.

Comment: Why is ABGKMN not the solution?

Comment: @Ingo: we are talking about sub-strings ( continuous characters)

Comment: @zakinster: you don't have to iterate over each character. You can keep ahash function for that. So, Overall it would be O(n*n)

Comment: @code_hacker You should post the code of your `O(n²)` solution because it seems that no one actually understood why you're really trying to achieve.

Comment: @zakinster: My mistake...yeah it will be O(n^3) because even if I'll maintain a hash of 256 length but still I'll have to iterate over the length of sub-string which is (n+1)/2. It will be O(n^3)

Comment: This is a pure algorithm question, not a programming question. I encourage you to ask on [cs.se]. I'm not recommending to migrate this question because the existing answers contain only code with no explanation and would not fly on CS.SE.

Comment: @Gilles I don't see a lot of these types of questions on [cs.se], there's a lot more of them on [so]. And an algorithm question is a programming question, regardless of whether we're dealing with actual code or not. Where they **actually** belong - I don't know. And, in my opinion, answers that contain only code are bad, regardless of where they are.

Comment: @Dukeling Huh? You can't have been looking very hard, [algorithms](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algorithms) is our biggest tag and has plenty of questions like this one.

Comment: @Gilles I only see the occasional question like this one on [cs.se]. I was considering giving you [the exact same link](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algorithms). I think we differ in opinion as to what "like this one" means. All those appear to be significant more difficult and more theoretical.

Comment: Isn't this a simple question? Just split everywhere you find two adjacent (or more) similar characters, ie. split and remove those, and then just pick the longest of the substrings inbetween? What am I not understanding here?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Computer Science itself, it is only for training the students' brain during education. To find a fast solution, or an overkill with an regex engine...

Answer (score 3):

for every *start* = 0 ... (n-1), try to expend *end* to the right-most position.

keep a bool array used[26] to remember if any character is already used.
suppose currently we finished (*start, end*)

for *start+1*,

- first clear by set: used[str[start]] = false;
- while ((end+1 < n) && (!used[str[end+1]])) { used[str[end+1]]=true; ++end;}

now we have check new (start, end). Total Complexity is O(N).

Comment: I like this most! It is short, fast, simple!. I hope it works, otherwise I have to delete my comment. When I see regex solution then i think that they have missed something in their SW-experience or education.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the solution in C#. I tested in in Visual studio 2012 and it works

```
public static int LongestSubstNonrepChar(string str) {

        int curSize = 0;
        int maxSize = 0;
        int end = 0;
        bool[] present = new bool[256];


        for (int start = 0; start < str.Length; start++) {
            end = start;
            while (end < str.Length) {
                if (!present[str[end]] && end < str.Length)
                {
                    curSize++;
                    present[str[end]] = true;
                    end++;
                }
                else
                    break;
            }
            if (curSize > maxSize) {
                maxSize = curSize;
            }
            //reset current size and the set all letter to false
            curSize = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < present.Length; i++)
                present[i] = false;
        }

            return maxSize;
    }
```

Comment: This is a clean solution! I can't believe nobody upvoted, passes all ~1000 cases on leetcode

Comment: You can optimize this solution by adding an if statement in the for loop like :::::                  if (maxSize <= (str.Length - start)) { --logic here }

Answer (score 2):

> Pretty tricky question, I give you an O(n) solution based on C#.

public string MaxSubStringKUniqueChars(string source, int k)
{

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(source) || k > source.Length) return string.Empty;

        var start = 0;
        var ret = string.Empty;
        IDictionary<char, int> dict = new Dictionary<char, int>();

        for (var i = 0; i < source.Length; i++)
        {
            if (dict.ContainsKey(source[i]))
            {
                dict[source[i]] = 1 + dict[source[i]];
            }
            else
            {
                dict[source[i]] = 1;
            }

            if (dict.Count == k + 1)
            {
                if (i - start > ret.Length)
                {
                    ret = source.Substring(start, i - start);
                }

                while (dict.Count > k)
                {
                    int count = dict[source[start]];
                    if (count == 1)
                    {
                        dict.Remove(source[start]);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dict[source[start]] = dict[source[start]] - 1;
                    }

                    start++;
                }
            }

        }
        //just for edge case like "aabbcceee", should return "cceee"
        if (dict.Count == k && source.Length - start > ret.Length)
        {
            return source.Substring(start, source.Length - start);
        }

        return ret;
    }
```

`

> //This is the test case.

```
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        var ret = Item001.MaxSubStringKUniqueChars("aabcd", 2);
        Assert.AreEqual("aab", ret);

        ret = Item001.MaxSubStringKUniqueChars("aabbccddeee", 2);
        Assert.AreEqual("ddeee", ret);

        ret = Item001.MaxSubStringKUniqueChars("abccccccccaaddddeeee", 3);
        Assert.AreEqual("ccccccccaadddd", ret);

        ret = Item001.MaxSubStringKUniqueChars("ababcdcdedddde", 2);
        Assert.AreEqual("dedddde", ret);
    }
```

Comment: Pretty neat solution.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
public static String getLongestSubstringNoRepeats( String string ){
    int iLongestSoFar = 0;
    int posLongestSoFar = 0;
    char charPrevious = 0;
    int xCharacter = 0;
    int iCurrentLength = 0;
    while( xCharacter < string.length() ){
        char charCurrent = string.charAt( xCharacter );
        iCurrentLength++;
        if( charCurrent == charPrevious ){
            if( iCurrentLength > iLongestSoFar ){
                iLongestSoFar = iCurrentLength;
                posLongestSoFar = xCharacter;
            }
            iCurrentLength = 1;
        }
        charPrevious = charCurrent;
        xCharacter++;
    }
    if( iCurrentLength > iLongestSoFar ){
        return string.substring( posLongestSoFar );
    } else {
        return string.substring( posLongestSoFar, posLongestSoFar + iLongestSoFar );
    }
}
```

Comment: That only prevents repeated adjacent characters. Given the string "nobody" it will report the entire string as having no repeated characters, but the OP's desired output would be "body".

Comment: According to the post "say string is AABGAKGIMN then BGAKGIMN is the solution". In this "solution" the G's are same.

Comment: [`getLongestSubstringNoRepeats("AABGAKGIMN")` doesn't appear to terminate](https://ideone.com/09hFZ8). Beyond that I think you have a bug in the length returned (possibly off by 1 or 2). And you return the length, not the actual string.

Comment: @Dukeling I have updated the code to return the string itself. It returns "ABGAKGIMN" for the test above.

Comment: @TylerDurden It should return just `BGAKGIMN`. And [there's another bug](https://ideone.com/39nSn3).

Comment: @Dukeling I guess I don't understand why "BGAKGIMN" is correct and "ABGAKGIMN" is not.

Comment: You're right. I misunderstood the OP's question. This looks like the solution. If the limitation is that the start or end character can't be a repeat of the previous (next) character, you could post-process when you check the length.

Comment: Presumable `BGAKGIMN` is correct because `A` can't appear because it was a repeated character in the original string. I'm just following the examples, the explanation leads me to a completely different problem.

Answer (score 0):

Let s be the given string, and n its length.

Define f(i) to be the longest [contiguous] substring of s ending at s[i] with distinct letters. That's unique and well-defined.

Compute f(i) for each i. It's easy to deduce from f(i-1) and s[i]:

- If the letter s[i] is in f(i-1), let j be the greatest position j < i such that s[j] = s[i]. Then f(i) is s[j+1 .. i] (in Python notation)
- Otherwise, f(i) is f(i-1) with s[i] appended.

The solution to your problem is any f(i) of maximal length (not necessarily unique).

You could implement this algorithm to run in O(n * 26) time, where 26 is the number of letters in the alphabet.

Answer (score 0):

public static int longestNonDupSubstring(char[] str) {

```
    int maxCount = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int maxEnd = 0;

    for(int i=1;i < str.length;i++) {

        if(str[i] != str[i-1]) {
            count++;
        }

        if (str[i] == str[i-1]) {
            if(maxCount<count) {
                maxCount = count;
                maxEnd = i;
            }
            count = 0;
        }

        if ( i!=str.length-1 && str[i] == str[i+1]) {
            if(maxCount<count) {
                maxCount = count - 1;
                maxEnd = i-1;
            }
            count = 0;
        }
    }

    int startPos = maxEnd - maxCount + 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < maxCount; i++) {

        System.out.print(str[startPos+i]);
    }

    return maxCount;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  //Given a string ,find the longest sub-string with all distinct characters in it.If there are multiple such strings,print them all.
  #include<iostream>
  #include<cstring>
  #include<array>

  using namespace std;

 //for a string with all small letters
 //for capital letters use 65 instead of 97

 int main()
 {

  array<int ,26> count ;

  array<string,26>largest;

  for(int i = 0 ;i <26;i++)
  count[i]=0;

  string s = "abcdefghijrrstqrstuvwxyzprr";
  string out = "";

  int k = 0,max=0;

  for(int i = 0 ; i < s.size() ; i++)
     { 
         if(count[s[i] - 97]==1)
           {  
              int loc = out.find(s[i]);

              for(int j=0;j<=loc;j++)   count[out[j] - 97]=0;

              if(out.size() > max) 
                {   
                   max = out.size();
                   k=1;
                   largest[0] = out;
                 }
             else if(out.size()==max) largest[k++]=out;

             out.assign(out,loc+1,out.size()-loc-1);
           }
         out = out + s[i];
         count[s[i] - 97]++;
      }

   for(int i=0;i<k;i++)  cout<<largest[i] << endl;
   //output will be
   // abcdefghijr
   // qrstuvwxyzp

  }
```

Comment: Please describe _what_ you are trying to achieve and _how_ (avoid magic numbers like `97`, especially when there is `'a'`). What is the tightest limit on time complexity that you can give for your solution? How does this answer `Can anyone suggest a better way to do it?`?

Answer (score 0):

Let me contribute a little as well. I have this solution with complexity will be O(N). The algorithm’s space complexity will be O(K), where K is the number of distinct characters in the input string.

```
public static int NoRepeatSubstring(string str)
    {
        int start = 0;
        int maxLen = 0;
        Dictionary<char, int> dic = new Dictionary<char, int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
        {
            char rightChar = str[i];
            // if the map already contains the 'rightChar', shrink the window from the beginning so that
            // we have only one occurrence of 'rightChar'
            if (dic.ContainsKey(rightChar))
            {
                // this is tricky; in the current window, we will not have any 'rightChar' after its previous index
                // and if 'start' is already ahead of the last index of 'rightChar', we'll keep 'windowStart'
                start = Math.Max(start, dic[rightChar] + 1);
            }

            if (dic.ContainsKey(str[i]))
                dic[str[i]] = i;
            else
                dic.Add(str[i], i);

            maxLen = Math.Max(maxLen, i - start + 1);

        }
        return maxLen;
    }
```

And here some Unit Tests:

```
Assert.Equal(3, SlideWindow.NoRepeatSubstring("aabccbb"));
Assert.Equal(2, SlideWindow.NoRepeatSubstring("abbbb"));
Assert.Equal(3, SlideWindow.NoRepeatSubstring("abccde"));
```

Answer (score -1):

```cs
string MaximumSubstringNonRepeating(string text)
{
    string max = null;
    bool isCapture = false;
    foreach (string s in Regex.Split(text, @"(.)\1+"))
    {
        if (!isCapture && (max == null || s.Length > max.Length))
        {
            max = s;
        }
        isCapture = !isCapture;
    }
    return max;
}
```

`.` matches any character. `( )` captures that character. `\1` matches the captured character again. `+` repeats that character. The whole pattern matches two or more repetitions of any one character. `"AA"` or `",,,,"`.

`Regex.Split()` splits the string at every match of the pattern, and returns an array of the pieces that are in between. (One caveat: It also includes the captured substrings. In this case, the one character that are being repeated. The captures will show up in between the pieces. This is way I just added the `isCapture` flag.)

The function cuts out all the repeated characters, and returns the longest piece that where in between the repeated each set of repeated characters.

```cs
>>> MaximumSubstringNonRepeating("AABGAKG") // "AA" is repeated
"BGAKG"

>>> MaximumSubstringNonRepeating("AABGAKGIMNZZZD") // "AA" and "ZZZ" are repeated.
"BGAKGIMN"
```

Comment: MY RegEx is pretty weak, could you explain how this works? --thnx